# Loading a local json file on demand using React or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

if I have a json file as below, I am using React (or even JavaScript is also fine), can somebody help me reading this file depending upon the Environment I set, like if I set it to local, all I need is to load the settings of the local and if I set it as Prod, all the settings of the prod must be loaded using React script or JavaScript, any ideas Geeks? - thanks in advance.

```
[
    {
        "Environment": "local",
        "local": {
            "url-1": "https://www.google.com",
            "url-2": "https://www.msn.com"
        },
        "Development": {
           "url-1": "https://www.google.co.in",
           "url-2": "https://www.msn.co.in"
        },
        "Test": {
           "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in",
           "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in"
        },
        "Prod": {
           "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in",
           "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Is this a react-native or electron application or something?

Comment: If bootstrapped using create-react-app, it should be easy for you.. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables. You can create files like .env, .env.local, .env.production with the environment variables... And start application setting NODE_ENV=test|production|development. Make sure don't set any passwords/secrets in it as its available in browser

Answer (score 1):

You can import the json file and set it on state.

```
import envConfig from './envConfig.json'

state = { envConfig }
```

And the have a helper function to read the `Environment` value and then update the state to have those values.

This would be the envConfig.json:

```
[{
    "Environment": "local",
    "local": {
        "url-1": "https://www.google.com",
        "url-2": "https://www.msn.com"
    },
    "Development": {
       "url-1": "https://www.google.co.in",
       "url-2": "https://www.msn.co.in"
    },
    "Test": {
       "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in",
       "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in"
    },
    "Prod": {
       "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in",
       "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in"
    }
}]
```

Comment: ```evalmachine.<anonymous>:1

import envConfig from './envConfig.json'
           ^^^^^^^^^


SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)

    at createScript (vm.js:277:10)

```

Comment: He doesn't have a `./envConfig.json` file to import from.

Comment: [link] (https://pastebin.com/kNJWpjhJ) That is the error he will get.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `case` method, combined with `const localCall = require("http://localhost/pathtoyourscript.js or URL here")` for a local call,
`const dev = require("URL")` etc.

Example:

```
switch(envSet) {
  case 'local':  // if (envSet === 'local')
    const localCall = require("http://localhost/pathtoyourscript.js or URL here");
    [break]

  case 'dev':  // if (envSet === 'dev')
    ...
    [break]
//add as many cases as needed
  default:
    ...
    [break]
}
```

etc.

Comment: This is JavaScript by the way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack you can make use of the **DefinePlugin**.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage

In your webpack config, in the plugins section you can add the DefinePlugin.

```
plugins: [
    // Some other plugins already defined.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({"process.env.MY_ENV": JSON.stringify(process.env.MY_ENV)})
         ]
```

This rewrites all the occurences of `process.env.MY_ENV` in your JS files with the actual environment variable `MY_ENV` when you run the code through webpack.

And given a config.json like below

```
{
    "local": {
        "url-1": "https://www.google.com",
        "url-2": "https://www.msn.com"
    },
    "Development": {
        "url-1": "https://www.google.co.in",
        "url-2": "https://www.msn.co.in"
    },
    "Test": {
        "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in",
        "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl.co.in"
    },
    "Prod": {
        "url-1": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in",
        "url-2": "https://www.somedifferenturl2.co.in"
    }
}
```

It can be used in a React component like below.

```
import React from "react";
import config from "./config.json";

function App() {
  const environment = process.env.MY_ENV;
  const envConfig = config[environment];
  // Do anything with the envConfig
  console.log(envConfig);

  return <h1>Hello</h1>;
}

export default App;
```

Starting your server with command `MY_ENV=VirtualEnv yarn start`, webpack converts the code to

```
function App() {
  const environment = "VirtualEnv";
  const envConfig = _config_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[environment]; // Do anything with the envConfig

  console.log(envConfig);
  return react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.createElement("h1", {
    __source: {
      fileName: _jsxFileName,
      lineNumber: 10
    },
    __self: this
  }, "Hello");
}
```